# Limit of a decreasing sequence of measurable sets.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, with measure $\mu$. Let $\{E_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ be a sequence of measurable sets, with $E_{n+1} \subseteq E_n, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, that is a decreasing sequence, and $\mu(E_n)=+ \infty, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $E=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_n$ the limit set of the sequence, $E$ is measurable for definition. Is true that $\mu(E)=+\infty$?
If not in all cases, is true with $X=\mathbb{R}^{N}$, $\mathcal{A}$ the collection of Lebesgue-measurable sets, and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $E_n=(n,\infty)$ as subsets of $\Bbb R$. Similar examples can be found for general $\Bbb R^N$, in particular the set of all $\vec{x}$ such that $\lVert\vec{x}\rVert>n$.

Comment: Ok, with $E_n=(0,+ \infty)$ the limit set of the sequence is the empty set because natural numbers are non-limitated.
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What is the measure of $[n, \infty)$

Comment: @user726608: The same as the measure of $(n,\infty).$

Comment: Okay, so it's just the length of the interval which is $\infty$?

Comment: @user726608: That's right.